# Python regex : adding space after comma only if not followed by a number

Tags: python, regex, str-replace

I want to add spaces after and before comma's in a string only if the following character isn't a number (9-0).  I tried the following code:

```
newLine = re.sub(r'([,]+[^0-9])', r' \1 ', newLine)
```

But it seems like the `\1` is taking the 2 matching characters and not just the comma. 
Example:

```
>>> newLine = "abc,abc"
>>> newLine = re.sub(r'([,]+[^0-9])', r' \1 ', newLine)
"abc ,a bc"
```

Expected Output:

```
"abc , abc"
```

How can I tell the `sub` to take only the 'comma' ?

Comment: 'preceding' means "coming-before" but you use it as "coming-after".  You perhaps mean 'following'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this one:

```
newLine = re.sub(r'[,]+(?![0-9])', r' , ', newLine)
```

Here using negative lookahead `(?![0-9])` it is checking that the comma(s) are not followed by a digit.

Your regex didn't work because you picked the comma and the next character(using `([,]+[^0-9])`) in a group and placed space on both sides.

**UPDATE:** If it is not only comma and other things as well, then place them inside the character class `[]` and capture them in group `\1` using `()`

```
newLine = re.sub(r'([,/\\]+)(?![0-9])', r' \1 ', newLine)
```

Comment: Thanks ! , how can I expand it to be comma/slash/backslash ? (since I used \1 and now I have to write the specific char to place (And I don't want it to be 3 separate lines)

Comment: @SagiLow yes, you can do that too. Please see my updated answer. You'll find how I have captured that in group(`\1`).